# is Crystal Report generate stacked bar chart of this style? Sample is attached in image

Tags: crystal-reports, stacked-bar-chart

I Need a report in crystal Report with the attached image style. Can Crystal reports support it?

[image: Sample Style]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you also need to show an indicator for the current patient score. Perhaps also a marker for a target/previous/benchmark value.

Since the scales are static, you can underlay a **static image for each type of scale**. You can then superimpose a **dynamically positioned "marker" image** (e.g. vertical line or arrow) using Crystal's support for dynamic expression. Here is an example of such a solution:
[image]

Another option, if you are flexible about the type of chart, is to use a **bullet chart**. They are an excellent choice for showing these type of performance ranges with intuitive performance & benchmark markers. There is at least one Crystal Reports User Function Library (UFL) that supports creating bullet charts in Crystal Reports. Here is an image of a report with bullet charts:
[image: Bullet Charts in Crystal Reports]